# Organizing semaphores into a pyramid

Tags: c, homework, thread-safety

My homework was to organize semaphores into a pyramid. The task was accomplished, but I ended up with this long ugly conditional and was wondering if anyone can see a better way/algorithm to accomplish the same thing.

```
if (me==0) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[1]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[2]);
    signal_sem(semaphore[0]);

}

if (me==1) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[3]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[4]);

}
if (me==2) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[4]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[5]);

}

if (me==3) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[6]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[7]);

}
if (me==4) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[7]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[8]);

}
if (me==5) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[8]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[9]);

}
if (me==6) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[10]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[11]);

}
if (me==7) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[11]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[12]);

}
if (me==8) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[12]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[13]);

}

if (me==9) {
    wait_sem(semaphore[13]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[14]);

}
```

Comment: You could use a `switch`

Comment: Yeah. A `switch` is a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't even use a `switch` here:

```
wait_sem(semaphore[me*2+1]);
wait_sem(semaphore[me*2+2]);
if (me==0) {
    signal_sem(semaphore[0]);    
}
```

Edit: I see the sequence is not quite linear. If you can come up with an easy mapping between `me` and the indices, this will work (but with a different formula). Otherwise, a `switch` statement may be the easiest way.

You can also bury the `switch` inside a map by mapping the input ints to the two indices (`std::map<int, std::pair<int, int> >`). It essentially does the same thing, but you can hide the ugly in a header file.

Comment: Potential maintenance issues here...

Comment: For `me==9` you should wait for 13 and 14, not 19 and 20

Comment: Sorry this migrated right as I was editing, then I had to create an account. Avoiding extraneous code is a good thing, but it probably will not work here.

Answer (score 3):

I think using `if` is ok, but please note that using `else if` clauses are also important for your code's performance.

Here is another way to do the job. Someone told me that data structures are easier to comprehend than control flows, so let's turn your `if` statements into `data tables`

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
}MY_TYPE;

MY_TYPE me[10] =
{
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4},
   {4, 5},
   {6, 7},
   {7, 8},
   {8, 9},
   {10, 11},
   {11, 12},
   {12, 13},
   {13, 14},
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      wait_sem(semaphore[me[i].a]);
      wait_sem(semaphore[me[i].b]);
      if (i == 0)
      {
         signal_sem(semaphore[i]);
      }
   }
```

I believe the `if/else` clause in `for` could be encapsulated by other utility functions, so maybe you can try it yourself :)

Comment: Nice solution. As the structure is used nowhere else and is not modified, I would make it `const` and simplify it a bit by removing the  `typedef` and `MY_TYPE` so that `me[10]` is just an anonymous `struct`

Comment: I like this: similar to my answer, but better given the non-regular nature of the number boundaries. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Switch statements are quite helpful in such cases.  They are also more efficient than your series of `if` statements which has to check all of them even after it finds the one it is looking for.  The `switch` will immediately branch to the correct one and skip all the others.  Is that helpful?

```
switch(me)
{
  case 0:
  wait_sem(semaphore[1]);
  wait_sem(semaphore[2]);
  signal_sem(semaphore[0]);
  break;

  case 1:
  wait_sem(semaphore[3]);
  wait_sem(semaphore[4]);
  break;

  //etc.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always wait on two semaphores and sometimes signal one semaphore. By calculating the index of the semaphores to wait on, you can shorten the code:

```
assert(me >= 0);

if (me < 10) {
    // Find the unique n s.t. T_n <= me < T_{n+1} where {T_n}_n are the triangular numbers
    int n = (int)(0.5 * (sqrt(1+8*me)-0.99));
    // then calculate nextPos := me + (T_{n+1} - T_n)
    int nextPos = me + n + 1;
    wait_sem(semaphore[nextPos]);
    wait_sem(semaphore[nextPos + 1]);
}

if (me == 0) {
    signal_sem(semaphore[0]);    
}
```